# Why is my python function only populating a dictionary with one line from a file?

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I have a file with 11 lines.  I'm writing a function that will skip the line containing "XYZ" and return the first and second columns of the rest of the lines in the file.  When I run the module, it skips the "XYZ" line, but only returns the first of the remaining lines.

```
def popdict(my_file):
    for line in my_file:
        if "XYZ" in line:
            pass
        else:
            x = line.split()
            a = x[1]
            b = x[0]
            d[a] = b
            return d
```

Strangely, when I test the `for` loop in the interpreter (i.e., I do not import it as a module), it yields the correct lines.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your `return` inside the for-loop returns from function the function the first time your else clause is executed!

Answer (score 0):

You return from the outer function the first time you find a line without "XYZ".  If you want to wait until end of file, then remove the **return** statement from the loop:

```
def read_to_dict():
    for line in my_file:
        if "XYZ" not in line:
            x = line.split()
            a = x[1]
            b = x[0]
            d[a] = b

    return d
```

Answer (score 0):

You should `return` just after the loop over the file finish:

```
def popdict(my_file):
    for line in my_file:
        if "XYZ" in line:
            pass
        else:
            x = line.split()
            a = x[1]
            b = x[0]
            d[a] = b
    return d
```